# How to prove a function given by an integral is differentiable?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

If the integral functions are $\int_{0}^{x}zf(z)dz$ and $\int_{x}^{\infty}zf(z)dz$. where $z$ and $x$ both are non-negative values. $f(x)$ is a continuous function like a probability density function. How to prove that these functions are differentiable? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is continuous, then $zf(z)$ and $z^2f(z)$ are continuous. The result now follows just from the fundamental theorem of calculus (assuming that either $f$ is continuous on a closed, bounded interval $[a,b]$ and $x\in (a,b)$ or that it is continuous on some set $[a,\infty)$, $x\in (a,\infty)$, and the given integral exists).

Comment: You can just use the fundamental theorem of calculus for the bounded case, then an obvious extension in the other (break the integral up into two pieces, one from $x$ to say $2a$ and one from $2a$ to $\infty$).

Comment: @Aeeh No problem, I hope that it helped!

Comment: $zf(z)$ continous in a bounded interval which means the given intergral exsits, but this does not mean the intergral function can be differentiable? is that right.

Comment: It does. The fundamental theorem of calculus tells us that we can differentiate the integral. Do you know this  theorem?

Comment: for example $\int_{-1}^{1} |x| dx$ this one is continous and intergral exists but it is not differentiable at x=0.

Comment: 1. Sure, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part 2. Your example is a number, not a function. 3. We're talking about differentiating the function $F(x)=\int_a^x f(s)\, ds$ for $f$ continuous, not differentiating $f$. Of course $f$ need not be differentiable, we didn't assume that it was.

Comment: I got it, really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Aeeh Awesome, and you're welcome!